# Aws Organization - handover the member account to other parties

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

I am helping my client for developing website from frontend to backend.

After the website launch, I will help clients to host for 2 years.

After 2 years, I need to handover the whole website to my client, including the frontend and backend. Therefore, I am finding a way to handover better in the future.

For web hosting, I am using Cloudfront.
For server hosting, I am using EC2
And more Aws services are being used.

Currently I am considering to use Aws Organization to create a member account(`MemberA`).

After creating the `MemberA`, I will login `MemberA` to create the Aws service I need.
At this point, my Root account can pay the bill for the services `MemberA` use.

After 2 years, if I handover the whole project to my client,
What should I do to remove the relationship between my Root account and `MemberA`, so that I can give the `MemberA` account to my client and let them pay for their own bill?

Update 1:
are `Move` or `Remove from Organization` in below image able to solve my question?

[image]

Update 2:

From [aws doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/organizations-move-accounts/),

> When a member account leaves an Organization, all charges incurred by the account are charged directly to the standalone account. Even if the account move takes only a minute to process, it's likely that some charges are incurred by the member account.
> If you need help updating the payment method for the member account, contact AWS Support.
> Be sure that you have a plan to address these charges incurred by the member account. For example, if you are asked to add a credit card to the member account to cover the charges, plan an internal process to reimburse the linked account for using its own payment method during the migration.
> When the member account is added to the new Organization, charges are billed to the new payer account.

Is that means I can do the followings steps to transfer account?

```
1. Ask my client to create Aws account(called ClientAcc etc) if they do not have it
2. Remove the member account(MemberA) from my Root account
3. ClientAcc Send an invite to the MemberA
4. MemberA accept the invite
```

Comment: I'm not sure what happens when an account is "removed" from an organization. You will _probably_ need to provide billing information immediately. I wonder if you can skip #2 and simply have them invite the account.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to give root credentials (for the account you are handing-over) to your client and ask them to:

- Update the billing information by providing their own credit card, or inviting their own Parent account to 'own' the account
- Update the contact information so that they become the responsible party for the account

I think you're also meant to notify AWS, since you agreed to the Terms & Conditions.

From [Transfer your AWS account to another person or organization](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/transfer-aws-account/):

> To assign ownership of an AWS account and its resources to another party or organization, contact AWS Support for help:
>
> - Create a Support case with a Category of **Ownership Transfer**
> - AWS Support will contact you and help you transfer your account ownership.

Comment: It seems not appropriate to give root credentials to my client. What if they delete my aws resources?

Comment: You would be giving the root credentials for the account you are handing-over, not your Master account.

Comment: oic, is it possible to use the flow in my `update 2`?

Comment: Those steps don't actually include anything to give access to the new owners (eg an Admin login), unless perhaps taking ownership of an account creates an IAM Role that can be assumed. Frankly, I'm not sure!